# Angular submit form in modal after pressing enter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am building an angular application that uses an Angular Material Dialog component containing a form.

The following example is provided by blog post of [angular-university](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/) but is so generic that it can also perfectly explain my problem. The form logic is put within the `mat-dialog-content` tags, the actions is put in the `mat-dialog-actions`. How can I modify this in such a way that I can submit my form by pressing enter?

**template.html**

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{description}}</h2>

<mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="form">

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput
                placeholder="Course Description"
               formControlName="description">
    </mat-form-field>
      ....

</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button class="mat-raised-button"(click)="close()">Close</button>
    <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary"(click)="save()">Save</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Normally I get this functionallity by wrapping everything with `form` tags, including my submit button, this isn't possible in this scenario since the form needs to be split by content and actions. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to add a `@HostListener` like so:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.enter') 
onEnter() {
    save();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess it would work, but doens't feel right. Isn't this functionality that basically everybody requires using a form in a modal?

Comment: Right. Did you add `type=submit` to the button?
You could also add a `form` just where the inputs are

Answer (score 0):

Import HostListener decorator from angular core.Then use it:

```
@HostListener(keydown.enter)
someFunc() {
this.save();
}
```